# Пытаюсь использовать SimpleAdapter, получаю ошибку

Tags: android, java

```
01-02 18:57:41.146  30794-30794/com.example.PoemsAndFace E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
        at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.bindView(SimpleAdapter.java:160)
        at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.createViewFromResource(SimpleAdapter.java:126)
        at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.getView(SimpleAdapter.java:114)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2207)
        at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:1040)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15635)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4919)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1411)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:698)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15635)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4919)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15635)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4919)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1411)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:698)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15635)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4919)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2223)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15635)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2165)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1249)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1443)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1139)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4872)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:776)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:579)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:548)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:762)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5392)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Что не так то?, создал только один hashMap и добавил в ArrayList

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пытаетесь обратиться к 1 элементу массива, хотя элемент всего один!

Comment: именно! `String[]{"TEXT,IMAGE"},new int[]{R.id.textView,R.id.imageView}`

я так понимаю должно быть 

`String[]{"TEXT","IMAGE"},new int[]{R.id.textView,R.id.imageView}`

С новым годом! Не пейте много :-)